# game kit several server & several client

Tags: objective-c, ios, gamekit

If i have 1 server and several clients (all peers know session name) - it's no problem.
But 2 server i have problem.
How will client to know sessionID, what is session create for connect to server, how are they choose server? I don't want to use peer picker. Ty for any ans.

Comment: self.session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:SESSION_ID(how to know) displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeClient];

Comment: And if i have 2 different servers with 1 sessionID. What's happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.serverArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    self.session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:nil displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeClient];

    self.session.delegate = self;

    [self.session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:NULL];

    self.session.available = YES;
}

- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state {

    NSString *serverName = [session displayNameForPeer:peerID];

    [self.serverArray addObject:serverName];

    [self.availableServers reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.serverArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ClientGameViewController *clientGameViewController = [[ClientGameViewController alloc] init];

     clientGameViewController.serverName = [self.serverArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    clientGameViewController.serverSessionName = [self.serverArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     [self.view addSubview:clientGameViewController.view];
}
```